# How do I know when my service is called from a broadcast receiver vs Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcast

So, I have a service for my app that is always running if the user turns it on.  It listens with a broadcast receiver for `USER_PRESENT` to show a message.  It is only supposed to show a message on unlocking.

The problem is though, when Android runs out of memory and kills it, then restarts it, it will show the message again, even if the user hasn't just unlocked their device.  Is there a way to know who called the service?

I use `service.START_NOT_STICKY`, but would `service.START_STICKY` be better for this job?  I guess I don't fully understand the differences but I'm pretty sure I want `NOT_STICKY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `action` field in the `intent` to a specific string when you call your receiver and then check it in `onReceieve`.

If it has your string then you called it , otherwise someone else.